# NoMethodError (undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

This is the error I have received:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass):  
app/controllers/concerns/withdraws/withdrawable.rb:20:in `create'
```

This is the part of the code in question:

```
def create
  @withdraw = model_kls.new(withdraw_params)

  @verified = current_user.id_document_verified?
  @local_sum = params[:withdraw][:sum]

  if !@local_sum
    render text: I18n.t('private.withdraws.create.amount_empty_error'), status: 403
    return
  end

  if !@verified && channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit < @local_sum <<<<<- Here is the error
    render text: I18n.t('private.withdraws.create.unverified_withdraw_limit_error', limit: channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit), status: 403
    return
  end
```

That's all my code:

https://github.com/DigitalCoin1/Spero-Exchange

The error in question is in this file:

https://github.com/DigitalCoin1/Spero-Exchange/blob/rebuild-peatio/app/controllers/concerns/withdraws/withdrawable.rb

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, [(almost) everything is Ruby is an object](https://www.eriktrautman.com/posts/ruby-explained-objects-and-methods)... including `nil`.

Keeping that in mind, consider what happens when you call a method that doesn't exist on `nil`:

```
irb(main):001:0> nil.something
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):1
NoMethodError (undefined method `something' for nil:NilClass)
```

Additionally, in Ruby operators such as `>`, `<`, and `==` are actually method calls. So, for example, an instance of `Integer` such as `3` has a method defined on it called `<` and when you call `3 < 4`, that calls the method on that instance. This works like that because in Ruby you can omit parentheses when making method calls. For example:

```rb
irb(main):001:0> 3 < 4
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 3.<(4)
=> true
```

So putting these two examples together:

```
irb(main):014:0> nil < 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):14
NoMethodError (undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass)
```

---

Now, let's take a look at your code.

You're getting the exception:

```rb
NoMethodError (undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass)
```

On this line:

```rb
!@verified && channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit < @local_sum
```

Looking at this code, you are only calling `<` in one place. This means that whatever is to the left of it (`channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit`) must be `nil`.

---

There are a few ways we can fix this... The best way, (in my opinion) is to make sure that `channel.currency_obj` can never be `nil`. I unfortunately don't have enough code to show you exactly how to do that, so let's look at some other options...

We can use [Ruby 2.3+'s safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) (`&.`) -- but it's a little weird to use with an operator like `<`.

```rb
channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit&. < @local_sum
```

*Note: in this example the expression will evaluate to `nil` and because `nil` is falsey the conditional will return false.*

Or, we can just add another expression to our conditional to check for `nil`:

```rb
!@verified && channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit && channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit < @local_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

The error happened when `channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit` return `nil` or `@local_sum` is nil.

And it can't compare `nil` value.

You must check `@local_sum` again, and make sure that it have a value. Or `channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit` make sure that it have a value.

But i guess that `channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit` return `nil`.

That your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass):  
app/controllers/concerns/withdraws/withdrawable.rb:20:in `create'
```

This error denotes that it is trying to compare `<` for a `nil` value.
Can you please `print` and check `channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit` and `@local_sum` before the error statement.

To avoid `nil` errors you can include `nil check`.

```
if channel.currency_obj.withdraw_limit != nil and @local_sum != nil
```